# Can I use DisplaySwitch to change monitors and resolution?

Tags: multiple-monitors, powershell, resolution

I have two monitors and have to be changing to one monitor and resolutions very often. I've been trying different commands but still no luck to get to my desired settings. Windows 10 btw

```
DisplaySwitch /external  Disconnect 2

DisplaySwitch.exe /internal  Disconnect 2

DisplaySwitch /?
```

What I want is to disconnect the monitor 2 and set a different resolution for the monitor 3. And also revert back when done. How can I do this with a batch script?

Comment: See/follow [SU link1](https://superuser.com/questions/1214072/disable-enable-2nd-3rd-monitor-programmatically-win10)
 / [SU link2](https://superuser.com/questions/308154/how-can-i-enable-disable-monitors-from-the-command-line)
 / [SU link3](https://superuser.com/questions/29450/how-to-do-a-powershell-or-other-script-to-change-screen-resolution)

Answer (score 0):

I use a program call Display Changer by 12 noon.

https://12noon.com/?page_id=80

They have plenty of documentation on how to switch and detach.  I use a batch script that plainly has:
dccmd.exe -width=1280 -height=1024.